# custom class with its own QTimer and QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtimer

I would like to create a class that has its own QTimer and QThread for some projects for Robot's sensors. After some searching, this is what I came up with

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>


//#####################( Robot Class  )#########################3

class Robot : public QObject
{
public:
    Robot(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Robot();

private:
    QTimer  *mQTimer;
    QThread *mQThread;

public slots:
    void update();

};

Robot::Robot(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
     mQTimer = new QTimer(0);
    mQThread = new QThread(this);

    mQTimer->setInterval(1);
    mQTimer->moveToThread(mQThread);

    connect(mQTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    connect(mQThread, SIGNAL(started()), mQTimer, SLOT(start()));

   mQThread->start();
   //mQTimer->start();

}

Robot::~Robot()
{
    delete mQTimer;
    delete mQThread;
}

void Robot::update()
{
    qDebug() << "Robot is updating ...";
}

//##################( Main )###########################
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Robot *myRobot = new Robot(0);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::update() in ..\untitled1\main.cpp:34
QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::update() in ..\untitled1\main.cpp:34
```

Comment: You are missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro on your `Robot` class.

Comment: Also, if you are using Qt5 - use new connect syntax, it will show you all the errors at compile time.

Comment: @RA, I've added the `Q_OBJECT` macro but I'm getting `main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const`

Comment: @CroCO Two problems: 1. You're not building moc output for that file. Assuming everything is in `main.cpp`, you need to add `#include "main.moc"` at the end of that file. 2. You must re-run qmake after making such changes. Your project will now build correctly.

Comment: The biggest problem is of course that your code makes no sense, and I hope you understand that. Running the timer in another thread only adds overhead. You're also counting on availability of 1ms timers - that's not a given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the Q_OBJECT macro in your class also try to avoid naming the methods like that because you can mix it with Qt methods names. Also make additional header and cpp file for each class you create in this case make robtot.h and robot.cpp.

```
class Robot : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Robot(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Robot();
...
```

Comment: I'm getting `main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const`

Comment: Try clean the solution, run qmake and rebuild.

Comment: the only thing that solved this problem after adding the macro is by generating an independent header file for Robot class. Please add this in your answer so that I can accept it for further reference.

Comment: Use Qt creator for creating class all the time and it will create different header and cpp file for each of your classes also you will have the #ifndef and #define predecessor directives that will protect you from including your class more then one time in some file. I am glad that you solved your problem mate. :)

Comment: @CroCo There's no need to add an independent header file. For a `foo.cpp` file with one or more `Q_OBJECT` macros in it, you must `#include "foo.moc"` at the end of the file. That's all. Make sure you re-run `qmake` after such changes (in Creator, right-click on the top project node and select "Run qmake"). This will modify the make file so that `foo.cpp` is passed through the moc to generate `foo.moc`, etc.

Comment: @KubaOber, according to "C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4" I'm quoting `For moc to work correctly, we must put the class definition in a header file, separate from the implementation file.`

Comment: @CroCo That's a mistake in the book - it wasn't correct even for Qt 4. I'd be more worried if such inaccuracies were in the documentation. Recall that that book hasn't been kept up to date, and hasn't been fixed either.

Answer (score 1):

The below works for me. You forgot the `Q_OBJECT` macro and to include the moc output that defines the static metadata for `Robot`.

There's of course no point to this code, since the `Robot::update` slot will execute in the main thread.

Your code has two threads: the main thread, where the `Robot` object lives, and the `robot.mThread`, where the timer lives. The timer will time out in the `mThread`, and will queue a slot call on the main thread. That slot call will end up invoking `robot.update` with `a.exec` on the stack.

Note that there's no need to explicitly have the timer and the thread allocated on the heap using `new`. They should be direct members of `Robot`, or of its PIMPL.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class Robot : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   QTimer mTimer;
   QThread mThread;
public:
   Robot(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
      connect(&mTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Robot::update);;
      mTimer.start(1000);
      mTimer.moveToThread(&mThread);
      mThread.start();
   }
   Q_SLOT void update() {
      qDebug() << "updating";
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   Robot robot;
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

It would make more sense to move the entire robot to its own thread. Note that when you do that, you need to set parentage on all objects owned by robot, so that they all switch threads along with the `Robot` object.

The `Thread` class fixes the long standing usability bug of `QThread` - it turns it into a truly RAII class that can be safely destructed at any time.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class Thread : public QThread {
   using QThread::run;
public:
   ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); }
};

class Robot : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   QTimer mTimer;
   int mCounter;
public:
   Robot(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent), mTimer(this), mCounter(0) {
      connect(&mTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Robot::update);;
      mTimer.start(1000);
   }
   Q_SLOT void update() {
      qDebug() << "updating";
      if (++mCounter > 5) qApp->exit();
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   Robot robot;
   Thread thread;
   robot.moveToThread(&thread);
   thread.start();
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `Cannot open include file: 'main.moc'`

Comment: @CroCo As long as your source file is named "main.cpp" and you are using `qmake` or `cmake` to build the project, you should be fine. Make sure you do a clean rebuild, or at least force a `qmake` or `cmake` re-run first. It works, I have hundreds of source files like that. You only get the error because you didn't run `qmake` (or cmake) since adding the `#include` line to main.cpp.

Comment: It is working now. Thank you so much. Something new to me.